Azure VM , connects with sharepoint to convert the data
I have a folder with some data and a .exe file which converts this data into another format in sharepoint. How can I connect this to azure VM and run the .exe in VM and store the converted data there so that I can do the rest of my project in VM.
I know I can copy sharepoint data to azure using datafactory, but I am not sure how to run a .exe in there.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Azure VM , connects with sharepoint to convert the data

You can follow the steps below to copy data from SharePoint to an Azure VM and execute the .exe files.

Create a VM, or skip this step if you already have one.
Copy the files from SharePoint to Azure Blob storage, then copy them from the storage account to the Azure VM.

You can use logic app or data factory to copy files to storage account, then use azcopy command to copy the files to storage account to VM, follow the MS Doc for installing Azcopy.
azcopy copy "C:\local\path" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D" --recursive=true



Once copy the files to VM, you can execute the .exe files from outside of the VM with below commands.

Copy the below script in Azure VM
script.ps1
 $exePath = "C:\file.exe"
$dataInputPath = "C:\data"
$dataOutputPath = "C:\output\data"
Start-Process -FilePath $exePath -ArgumentList $dataInputPath, $dataOutputPath -NoNewWindow -Wait
Write-Output "Data conversion completed."


Once you have copied the above script to the Azure VM, execute the following script to run the .exe file on the Azure VM
 $scriptPath = "C:\script.ps1"
 $username = "yourVMUsername"
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
 $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroupNamee -Name "VM_Name" -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath -Location "VM_Location" -Credential $credential


